# hardware transactional memory: _xbegin() return 0

Tags: c++, x86, transactional-memory, intel-tsx

By gcc docs: [x86-transactional-memory-intrinsics.html](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/X86-transactional-memory-intrinsics.html), when transaction failed/abort, **_xbegin()** should return a **abort status** . However, I find it return 0 sometimes. And the frequency is very high. What kind of situation that **_xbegin()**will return 0?

**After checking manual, I find many situations may cause this result. For example, CPUID, SYSTEMCALL, CFLUSH.etc**. However, I don't think my code has triggered any of them.

Here is my code: Simulating a small bank, a random account transfer 1$ to another account.

```
#include "immintrin.h"
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define n_threads 1
#define OPSIZE 1000000000
typedef struct Account{
    long balance;
    long number;
} __attribute__((aligned(64))) account_t;

typedef struct Bank{
    account_t* accounts;
    long size;
} bank_t;

bool done = 0;
long *tx, *_abort, *capacity, *debug, *failed, *conflict, *zero;

void* f1(bank_t* bank, int id){
    for(int i=0; i<OPSIZE; i++){ 
        int src = rand()%bank->size;
        int dst = rand()%bank->size;
        while(src == dst){
            dst = rand()%bank->size;
        } 

        while(true){
            unsigned stat =  _xbegin();
            if(stat == _XBEGIN_STARTED){
                bank->accounts[src].balance++;  
                bank->accounts[dst].balance--;
                _xend();
                asm volatile("":::"memory");    
                tx[id]++;
                break;
            }else{
                _abort[id]++;

                if (stat == 0){
                    zero[id]++;
                }
                if (stat & _XABORT_CONFLICT){
                    conflict[id]++;
                }
                if (stat & _XABORT_CAPACITY){
                    capacity[id]++;
                }
                if (stat & _XABORT_DEBUG){
                    debug[id]++;
                }
                if ((stat & _XABORT_RETRY) == 0){
                    failed[id]++;
                    break;
                }
                if (stat & _XABORT_NESTED){
                    printf("[ PANIC ] _XABORT_NESTED\n");
                    exit(-1);
                }
                if (stat & _XABORT_EXPLICIT){
                    printf("[ panic ] _XBEGIN_EXPLICIT\n");
                    exit(-1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
void* f2(bank_t* bank){
    printf("_heartbeat function\n");
    long last_txs=0, last_aborts=0, last_capacities=0, last_debugs=0, last_faileds=0, last_conflicts=0, last_zeros = 0;
    long txs=0, aborts=0, capacities=0, debugs=0, faileds=0, conflicts=0, zeros = 0;
    while(1){
        last_txs = txs;
        last_aborts = aborts;
        last_capacities = capacities;
        last_debugs = debugs;
        last_conflicts = conflicts;
        last_faileds = faileds;
        last_zeros = zeros;

        txs=aborts=capacities=debugs=faileds=conflicts=zeros = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<n_threads; i++){
            txs += tx[i];
            aborts += _abort[i];
            faileds += failed[i];
            capacities += capacity[i];
            debugs += debug[i];
            conflicts += conflict[i];
            zeros += zero[i];
        }

        printf("txs\t%ld\taborts\t\t%ld\tfaileds\t%ld\tcapacities\t%ld\tdebugs\t%ld\tconflit\t%ld\tzero\t%ld\n", 
            txs - last_txs, aborts - last_aborts , faileds - last_faileds, 
            capacities- last_capacities, debugs - last_debugs, conflicts - last_conflicts,
            zeros- last_zeros);

        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int accounts = 10240;

    bank_t* bank = new bank_t;
    bank->accounts = new account_t[accounts];
    bank->size = accounts;

    for(int i=0; i<accounts; i++){
        bank->accounts[i].number = i;
        bank->accounts[i].balance = 0;
    }

    thread* pid[n_threads];
    tx = new long[n_threads];
    _abort = new long[n_threads];
    capacity = new long[n_threads];
    debug = new long[n_threads];
    failed = new long[n_threads];
    conflict = new long[n_threads];
    zero = new long[n_threads];

    thread* _heartbeat = new thread(f2, bank);
    for(int i=0; i<n_threads; i++){
        tx[i] = _abort[i] = capacity[i] = debug[i] = failed[i] = conflict[i] = zero[i] =  0;
        pid[i] = new thread(f1, bank, i);
    }

//  sleep(5);
    for(int i=0; i<n_threads;i++){
        pid[i]->join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Supplements:

1. All accounts is 64bit aligned. I printed bank->accounts[0], bank->accounts[1](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/X86-transactional-memory-intrinsics.html) address. 0xf41080，0xf410c0。
2. Using -O0 and `asm volatile("":::"memory");`therefore there is no instruction reordering problems.
3. Abort rate increases at time. Here is the result

   ```
   txs     84      aborts          0       faileds 0       capacities      0     debugs  0       conflit 0       zero    0
   txs     17070804      aborts          71      faileds 68      capacities      9       debugs  0       conflit 3       zero    59
   txs     58838         aborts          9516662 faileds 9516661 capacities      0       debugs  0       conflit 1       zero    9516661
   txs     0             aborts          9550428 faileds 9550428 capacities      0       debugs  0       conflit 0       zero    9550428
   txs     0             aborts          9549254 faileds 9549254 capacities      0       debugs  0       conflit 0       zero    9549254
   ```
4. Even through n_threads is 1, the result is same.
5. If I add coarse lock after fallback as follow, the result seems be correct.

   ```
   int fallback_lock;

   bool 
   rtm_begin(int id)
   {   
       while(true) { 
           unsigned stat;
           stat = _xbegin ();
           if(stat == _XBEGIN_STARTED) {
               return true;
           } else {
               _abort[id]++;
               if (stat == 0){
                   zero[id]++;
               }
               //call some fallback function
               if (stat& _XABORT_CONFLICT){
                   conflict[id]++;
               }

               //will not succeed on a retry
               if ((stat &  _XABORT_RETRY) == 0) {
                   failed[id]++;
                   //grab a fallback lock
                   while (!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&fallback_lock,0,1)) {
                   }
                   return false;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ....

   in_rtm = rtm_begin(id);
   y = fallback_lock;
   accounts[src].balance--;
   accounts[dst].balance++;
   if (in_rtm){
       _xend();
   }else{
       while(!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&fallback_lock, 1, 0)){
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Hmm. Cursory inspection suggests things are fine (though, I have not run it, and it's been quite some time since I worked actively with TM). The  failure with 1 thread seems curious -- is it still failing if you pin the thread to a core? Similarly, the coarse lock result is a little curious. What happens if you back off (spinwait) instead?

Comment: It fails even when pinning the thread to a core. Someone suggests it could because tlb missing or cache missing. Because transaction abort go back to its start point and  as if interrupt never happens. So the mistake will happen next time.

Comment: That seems immensely awkward. :S Sorry, alas, I think we have exhausted my expertise here!

Comment: Which processor were you using? TSX is buggy and has been disabled on Haswell, Haswell-E, Haswell-EP and early Broadwell CPUs upon a microcode update.

Answer (score 1):

The hardware documentation on [RTM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524025) suggests the following:

> The value of EAX can be '0' following an RTM abort. For example, a CPUID instruction when used inside an RTM region causes a transactional abort and may not satisfy the requirements for setting any of the EAX bits. This may result in an EAX value of '0'.

(Where, EAX is the hardware register used to communicate status, that GCC will in turn return to you as the return value of )

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think CPUID or SYSTEMCALL cause the problem. I reedit my question and touch the whole code. Can you explain why a fallback coarse lock is needed?

Comment: Looks like there are a bunch of things that cause [aborts](http://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-tm/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Plenty little details in the original code.

Rule number zero : all C data shared by threads MUST be declared as volatile, the C optimizers are too clever and do lots of shortcuts (e.g. all your arrays for counting the failures).  Or better, C++ `std::atomic` or C `_Atomic` for synchronization variables, and other variables can be plain if access to them won't have data-race UB.

Did you evaluate the number of memory de-references in your RTM section ?
Did you notice that "capacities" was sometimes incremented by your code , which continues to hammer the hw merciless and heavily ?

There are plenty reasons for RTM aborts : interrupts, thread deschedule, thread migration across cores ..... Not complex to understand

There are other reasons harder to explain, like bringing the cache lines in L1 code and allow for a few cycles before latest data movements and `xbegin` .... this is hidden across the old documentation, but cache misses are a reason for aborts. In a real application, the dynamics are different.

Here is the modified code, after some debug

```
$ cat rtm_explore.cpp
#include "immintrin.h"
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define n_threads 4

typedef struct Account{
    int64_t balance;
    uint64_t number;
} __attribute__((aligned(64))) account_t;

typedef struct Bank{
    account_t* accounts;
    uint64_t size;
} bank_t;

volatile bool done = false;
volatile uint64_t *tx, *aabort, *capacity, *debug, *failed, *conflict, *zero;

volatile uint64_t bring_to_l1(void *addr)
{
   // read the data to force the cache line in L1 cache
   volatile uint64_t *ptr = (uint64_t *)addr;
   volatile uint64_t value = *ptr;  // store to stack memory to wait for the load result
   return value;
}

uint64_t my_rand()
{
   static uint64_t seed = 0x1234567812345678ull;
   seed = seed * 13 + 137;   // linear congruential generator, period = 2^64
   return (seed >> 13) ^ (seed << 13);
}

void nop(void)
{
   asm volatile (" nop\n":::);
   asm volatile (" nop\n":::);
   asm volatile (" nop\n":::);
   asm volatile (" nop\n":::);
   asm volatile (" nop\n":::);
   asm volatile (" nop\n":::);
}


void* f1(bank_t* bank, int id){
    while (!done){ 
        uint64_t src = my_rand() % bank->size;
        uint64_t dst = my_rand() % bank->size;
        while(src == dst){
            dst = my_rand() % bank->size;
        } 

        bool retry = true;
        while(!done && retry == true){
                // cache misses are 'notorious' (!) to trigger rtm failures  (need retries and higher capacities)
                // it is better to explicitely dereference, best effort, all the pointer chain
                // bring_to_l1(&bank);  
                // bring_to_l1(bank);  
                // bring_to_l1(bank->accounts);  
                // bring_to_l1(&bank->accounts[src].balance);  
                // bring_to_l1(&bank->accounts[dst].balance);  
                // bring_to_l1(&src);  
                // bring_to_l1(&dst);  

                // ideally, should use less dereferences to reduce the cache pressure
                // ptr_src = &bank->accounts[src].balance;  
                // ptr_dst = &bank->accounts[dst].balance;  
                // bring_to_l1(ptr_src);  
                // bring_to_l1(ptr_dst);  
                // transactional is just 2 pointers   xbegin(), *ptr_src++, *ptr_dst--, xend() 
                
                int64_t *ptr_src = &(bank->accounts[src].balance);  
                int64_t *ptr_dst = &(bank->accounts[dst].balance);  
                bring_to_l1(ptr_src);  
                bring_to_l1(ptr_dst);  

                // xbegin notoriously should not follow too closely a data movement. yuk (tm).
                nop();  

            // transactional section (start)
            unsigned stat =  _xbegin();
            if(stat == _XBEGIN_STARTED){
                (*ptr_src)++;
                (*ptr_dst)--;
                _xend();
            // transactional section (end)
                tx[id]++;
                retry = false;
                break;
            }else{
            // transactional section (fail)
            // Ideally, should use a locked section to complete the job.
                aabort[id]++;

                if (stat == 0){
                    zero[id]++;
                }
                if (stat & _XABORT_CONFLICT){
                    conflict[id]++;
                }
                if (stat & _XABORT_CAPACITY){
                    capacity[id]++;
                    usleep(1000);
                    break;    // no money transfer today in the bank.
                }
                if (stat & _XABORT_DEBUG){
                    debug[id]++;
                    break;    // No debug camera is allowed in any bank
                }
                if (stat & _XABORT_RETRY){
                    failed[id]++;
                }
                if (stat & _XABORT_NESTED){
                    printf("[ PANIC ] _XABORT_NESTED\n");
                    exit(-1);
                }
                if (stat & _XABORT_EXPLICIT){
                    printf("[ panic ] _XBEGIN_EXPLICIT\n");
                    exit(-1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
void* f2(bank_t* bank){
    printf("_heartbeat function\n");
    unsigned long long last_txs=0, last_aborts=0, last_capacities=0, last_debugs=0, last_faileds=0, last_conflicts=0, last_zeros = 0;
    unsigned long long txs=0, aborts=0, capacities=0, debugs=0, faileds=0, conflicts=0, zeros = 0;
    while(!done){
        sleep(1);

        last_txs = txs;
        last_aborts = aborts;
        last_capacities = capacities;
        last_debugs = debugs;
        last_conflicts = conflicts;
        last_faileds = faileds;
        last_zeros = zeros;

        txs=aborts=capacities=debugs=faileds=conflicts=zeros = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<n_threads; i++){
            txs += tx[i];
            aborts += aabort[i];
            faileds += failed[i];
            capacities += capacity[i];
            debugs += debug[i];
            conflicts += conflict[i];
            zeros += zero[i];
        }

        printf("txs %10llu aborts %10llu faileds %10llu capacities %10llu debugs %10llu conflicts %10llu zeros %10llu\n", 
            txs - last_txs, aborts - last_aborts , faileds - last_faileds, 
            capacities- last_capacities, debugs - last_debugs, conflicts - last_conflicts,
            zeros- last_zeros);

    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    uint64_t accounts = 10240;

    bank_t* bank = new bank_t;
    bank->accounts = new account_t[accounts];
    bank->size = accounts;
    done = false;

    for(int i=0; i<accounts; i++){
        bank->accounts[i].number = i;
        bank->accounts[i].balance = 0;
    }

    thread* pid[n_threads];
    tx = new uint64_t[n_threads];
    aabort = new uint64_t[n_threads];
    capacity = new uint64_t[n_threads];
    debug = new uint64_t[n_threads];
    failed = new uint64_t[n_threads];
    conflict = new uint64_t[n_threads];
    zero = new uint64_t[n_threads];

    thread* _heartbeat = new thread(f2, bank);
    for(int i=0; i<n_threads; i++){
        tx[i] = aabort[i] = capacity[i] = debug[i] = failed[i] = conflict[i] = zero[i] =  0;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n_threads; i++){
        pid[i] = new thread(f1, bank, i);
    }

    sleep(10);
    done = true;

    for(int i=0; i<n_threads;i++){
        pid[i]->join();
    }
    _heartbeat->join();

    long long plus = 0, minus = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<accounts; i++){
        int64_t balance = bank->accounts[i].balance;
        if (balance > 0) plus += balance ; else minus += balance;
    }
    printf("plus %lld minus %lld should match\n", plus, minus);

    return 0;
}
```

I added a bank balance at the end of the code, to check for any robbery orchestrated by RTM.

And now it displays this:

```
$ g++ -O3 -mrtm rtm_explore.cpp
$ ./a.out
_heartbeat function
txs    4790413 aborts       3332 faileds          3 capacities         87 debugs          0 conflicts          4 zeros       3241
txs    5928087 aborts       3231 faileds          4 capacities         92 debugs          0 conflicts          4 zeros       3135
txs    6433714 aborts       3217 faileds          2 capacities         85 debugs          0 conflicts          2 zeros       3130
txs    5833479 aborts       3237 faileds          4 capacities        101 debugs          0 conflicts          4 zeros       3132
txs    5431178 aborts       3263 faileds          5 capacities         95 debugs          0 conflicts          5 zeros       3163
txs    6197918 aborts       3213 faileds          0 capacities        101 debugs          0 conflicts          0 zeros       3112
txs    4725374 aborts       3350 faileds          0 capacities         76 debugs          0 conflicts          1 zeros       3273
txs    6080462 aborts       3206 faileds          3 capacities        101 debugs          0 conflicts          3 zeros       3102
txs    6565964 aborts       3205 faileds          3 capacities         90 debugs          0 conflicts          3 zeros       3112
txs    6162103 aborts       3219 faileds          2 capacities        101 debugs          0 conflicts          2 zeros       3116
plus 458699 minus -458699 should match
```

I will ignore all comments about RTM and HLE being microcoded-out in recent updates since the question was asked. It is really a beautiful concept which accelerates greatly concurrent code with (quite) low collision probabilities. I am a fan of "[Intel-TSX-Deprecation-643557-0023-20230608.pdf](https://cdrdv2-public.intel.com/643557/Intel-TSX-Deprecation-643557-0023-20230608.pdf)" and `sudo wrmsr 0x10f 4` for development-only purposes on Skylake-family CPUs, like the Kaby Lake this testing was done on.

Comment: *all C data shared by threads MUST be declared as volatile* - You never need `volatile`. 
 If not already protected by other synchronization, it should be `_Atomic`.  If other synchronization (e.g. `int tmp = atomic_load_explicit(&shared_var, memory_order_acquire); if (tmp) ...`) already guarantees that there's no data-race UB, then you don't need `volatile` or `_Atomic`.  [When to use volatile with multi threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58535118) (never, except as a performance hack for missed optimizations with _Atomic double or float.)

Comment: Also, this is a C++ question and your answer is written in C++, so `std::atomic<>` rather than `_Atomic`, and `shared_var.load(std::memory_order_acquire)`.

Comment: @peter : I wanted to keep things simple and prevent being fooled by the compiler/optimizer. Anyway atomic is never needed on x86 for data movement of size X aligned on X boundary (from bytes to long to SSE to AVX256 sizes)

Comment: Are you saying that compilers fail to treat `_xbegin()` and `_xend()` as memory barriers?  But I assume not because your `ptr_src` and `ptr_dst` are just plain pointers, not pointer-to-`volatile`.  That's the one case where you want to rely on something other than the `std::atomic` mechanism for atomicity, instead using RTM to turn both those load + modify + store ops into a transaction.

Comment: _xbegin() and _xend() are volatile intrinsics acting as a barrier for compiler.

Comment: if you look at the original code, there is a "done" variable unused, the remains of a failed way to stop the application correctly. I had plenty problems while displaying the heartbeat data. For that, volatile is just good enough. And I really wanted to end the code properly and check the bank balance :-) at the end of the program.

Comment: Simple is a poor excuse for legacy non-portable code.  Anyone writing multi-threaded lock-free code in C++ in 2024 should be familiar with `std::atomic`.  `volatile` doesn't prevent compile-time reordering with plain variables, so even on x86 you don't actually get `release`/`acquire` semantics.  The one use-case for `volatile` in your code is `bring_to_l1`, which should be defined as `*(volatile unsigned char*)ptr;`.  Forcing the load result to be copied to stack space with `volatile uint64_t value` is not helpful, you just need to deref a pointer-to-volatile.

Comment: What CPU are you using where `sudo wrmsr 0x10f 4` works?  I've read that some Intel CPUs (maybe Ice Lake) have RTM fully removed.  And I guess probably Alder Lake since the E-cores won't have it.  Which is a shame, I've been hoping they'd eventually fix it.  Maybe they have for their recent servers?

Comment: you forget about delayed instruction execution at run time. To be sure that a read is completed, there is no other choice than starting a write operation with dependency.

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8650U   (kabylake family 06 model 8e)

Comment: *To be sure that a read is completed, there is no other choice than starting a write operation with dependency.* - The store buffer allows out-of-order exec of stores, and speculative execution past stores.  Does `xbegin` wait for previous stores to retire and commit to L1d cache or something, but not wait for loads at all?  Would `lfence` be cheaper to wait for loads (and all previous instructions) to retire, which on x86 means the loads have actually received a value. (Weakly-ordered ISAs can let loads retire after they're known to not fault, even if the data hasn't arrived yet, but not x86)

Comment: *Anyway atomic is never needed on x86 for data movement of size X aligned on X boundary (from bytes to long to SSE to AVX256 sizes)* - you're unlikely to get an atomic load of `__int128` if you don't specifically request it with `atomic<__int128>`.  (With a new-enough GCC / libc / libatomic, on CPUs with AVX it will use `movaps` or `vmovaps` because vendors finally documented 128-bit atomicity).  [Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](//stackoverflow.com/a/36685056) - my answer there shows how to use `std::atomic` to cheaply take advantage of HW guarantees.

Comment: Also, `atomic<>` is how you avoid compiler optimizations like hoisting loads out of loops, not to mention stuff that mostly happens on non-x86 ISAs like how GCC makes AArch64 asm that's not guaranteed atomic until ARMv8.4 ([Which types on a 64-bit computer are naturally atomic in gnu C and gnu C++? -- meaning they have atomic reads, and atomic writes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71866535) - none.)

Comment: I'm aware that if you want 256-bit atomicity, you have it in practice on most CPUs, but no vendor-guaranteed / documented way to detect it.  https://rigtorp.se/isatomic/  And yes if you're looking at transactional memory, that can be a way to avoid a transaction sometimes.  But it's not a good suggestion in general.  Use `std::atomic` when it can do what you need.  It makes your code easy to port and recompile for other ISAs in the future.

Comment: Intel hw guarantees atomic read and write of data size X on X boundaries.

Comment: Yes, but ISO C++ doesn't for anything other than `atomic<>`.  That HW guarantee is what makes `atomic<>`  compile to cheap instructions (as long as you avoid `seq_cst` for stores).  GNU semantics for `volatile` are to use a single instruction for types up to register width, so that's a way to roll your own relaxed atomics on some compilers, but not for `__int128`.  (https://godbolt.org/z/qGMj9qjq5 - GCC doesn't inline `__atomic_load_16` even when compiling for a CPU with AVX, unfortunately, but libatomic will use `vmovaps` and `vmovq` + `vpextrq` or something like that.)

Comment: Also, the actual documented Intel guarantee is only for sizes up to 128-bit, or to 64-bit on CPUs without AVX.  256-bit  and 512-bit atomic load/store are atomic in practice on HSW and later, except Alder Lake E-cores, but we only have experimental testing to back that up.  (Still, Intel's documented guarantee of atomicity for any misalignment that doesn't cross a cache-line boundary on P6 and later CPUs, and the known fact that aligned 256-bit and 512-bit loads/stores are single operations that physically happen in parallel for all bits, make this pretty safe.)

Comment: __int128 is a gcc/clang construction over 64 bits integer registers, this is not a 128 bit element of the hw architecture (unlike xmm registers with 128 bit atomic properties).

Comment: from 11 to 14th generation, i9-11900, i9-12900, i9-13900, i9-14900 do not have transactional instructions. $ sudo wrmsr 0x10f 4 
wrmsr: CPU 0 cannot set MSR 0x0000010f to 0x0000000000000004

Comment: Exactly, the C++ way to take advantage of those HW guarantees is with `std::atomic` or `std::atomic_ref` which you can use with a 16-byte struct (which would have been a better example).  You only need to resort to using C++ with intrinsics as a high-level assembly language in cases where compilers do a bad job, or where you're taking advantage of HW behaviour that's not documented / guaranteed to be portable so compilers don't use it.